# how to get the Annotated object using aspectJ

Tags: java, aop, aspectj, java-ee-6, pointcut

I have an annotation like this:

```
@Inherited
@Documented
@Target(value={ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Restful {

}
```

I annotated this class like this:

```
@Restful
public class TestAspect {
   public String yes;
}
```

I have a pointcut like this:

```
@Pointcut("@annotation(com.rest.config.Restful)")
   public void pointCutMethod() {
}
```

I tried:

```
@Before("pointCutMethod()")
public void beforeClass(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
    System.out.println("@Restful DONE");
    System.out.println(joinPoint.getThis());
}
```

But getThis() returns null.

Basically I am trying to get that Object instance of TestAspect. How do I do it? Any clue? any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

With your annotation placed on the type only and the pointcut `@annotation(com.rest.config.Restful)` you are only going to match the static initialization join point for your type. As we can see if you use `-showWeaveInfo` when you compile (I slapped your code samples into a file called Demo.java):

```
Join point 'staticinitialization(void TestAspect.<clinit>())' in 
  Type 'TestAspect' (Demo.java:9) advised by before advice from 'X' (Demo.java:19)
```

When the static initializer runs there is no `this`, hence you get null when you retrieve it from `thisJoinPoint`. You haven't said what you actually want to advise but let me assume it is creation of a new instance of TestAspect. Your pointcut needs to match on execution of the constructor for this annotated type:

```
// Execution of a constructor on a type annotated by @Restful
@Pointcut("execution((@Restful *).new(..))")
public void pointcutMethod() { }
```

If you wanted to match methods in that type, it would be something like:

```
@Pointcut("execution(* (@Restful *).*(..))")
```

Comment: Thanks @Andy Clement but as you can see, i am trying to get an instance that is created in a java ee environment, (hint: java ee 6 is one of the tags), the new in execution would not work. it would work in se environment though. any clue about how to do it in the ee 6/7 environment?